# Return values not working

Tags: java

I'm a student in a into to Java course. I am trying to use an array of objects and a custom constructor to make a simple database. I am trying to pull the data that I thought I set but I keep getting responses of null or 0. Any help would be appreciated.

This what it prints out:

Student Data

Name:null

Gender:null

Hometown:null

Grade Level:0

Height in inches:0

```
package FinalProject;

public class UserClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
StudentData[] student = new StudentData[5];

student[0] = new StudentData();
student[0].setStudentName("Bob");
student[0].setStudentGender("Male");
student[0].setStudenthometown("Elpaso");
student[0].setStudentlevel(9);
student[0].setStudentHeight(69);

student[1] = new StudentData();
student[1].setStudentName("Suzie");
student[1].setStudentGender("Female");
student[1].setStudenthometown("Dallas");
student[1].setStudentlevel(11);
student[1].setStudentHeight(44);

student[2] = new StudentData();
student[2].setStudentName("Mark");
student[2].setStudentGender("Male");
student[2].setStudenthometown("Ft Worth");
student[2].setStudentlevel(9);
student[2].setStudentHeight(54);

student[3] = new StudentData();
student[3].setStudentName("Nick");
student[3].setStudentGender("Male");
student[3].setStudenthometown("Hartland");
student[3].setStudentlevel(12);
student[3].setStudentHeight(70);

student[4] = new StudentData();
student[4].setStudentName("Mckenna");
student[4].setStudentGender("Female");
student[4].setStudenthometown("Milwaukee");
student[4].setStudentlevel(8);
student[4].setStudentHeight(56);

System.out.println("Student Data");
System.out.println("Name:"+student[1].getStudentName());
System.out.println("Gender:"+student[1].getStudentGender());
System.out.println("Hometown:"+student[1].getStudenthometown());
System.out.println("Grade Level:"+student[1].getStudentlevel());
System.out.println("Height in inches:"+student[1].getStudentheight());  
}

}


package FinalProject;

public class StudentData {
private String StudentName;
private String StudentGender;
private String Studenthometown;
private int Studentlevel;
private int Studentheight;


public String getStudentName(){
    return StudentName;
}

public String getStudentGender(){
    return StudentGender;
}

public String getStudenthometown(){
    return Studenthometown;
}
public int getStudentlevel(){
    return Studentlevel;
}

public int getStudentheight(){
    return Studentheight;
}

public void setStudentName(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setStudentGender(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setStudenthometown(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setStudentlevel(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setStudentHeight(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: your setter methods are empty, so there wont be any change to the values you want to set for every specific instance of `StudentData`. I´d also suggest to provide a constructor with the values you are setting afterwards.

Comment: Please set the values in setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setter methods don't change the attributes of the `StudentData` class.

Use something like this:

```
public void setStudentName(String string) {
    this.StudentName= string;
}
```

BTW, you should use the Java naming conventions, this makes your code easier to read, i.e. attributes names should start with a lowercase letter, like

```
private String studentName;
```

You have to change your getter and setter methods accordingly, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help